# Subtracting in C adds and turns negative

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a simple calculator that asks how many numbers are needed (right now just for adding and subtracting) then collects those numbers for the user and does the corresponding math depending on what the user wants.

Here's my code:

```
            if (option == 1) {
                printf("ADDITION\n");
                printf("How many numbers do you need? ");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                printf("Enter %d numbers:\n", n);

                for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
                    scanf("%lf", &addNum);
                    sol = sol + addNum;
                }
                printf("Solution: %.2lf\n", sol);
            }
            if (option == 2) {
                printf("SUBTRACTION\n");
                printf("How many numbers do you need? ");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                printf("Enter %d numbers:\n", n);

                for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
                    scanf("%lf", &subNum);
                    sol = sol - subNum;
                }
                printf("Solution: %.2lf\n", sol);
            }
```

The addition works perfectly fine. The subtraction does not. I figured  if adding is working, then replacing the + with an - would suffice but I guess not. The problem I'm having is, for example:

```
ADDITION 
How many numbers do you need? 2
Enter 2 numbers:
10
5
Solution: 15.00

SUBTRACTION
How many numbers do you need? 2
Enter 2 numbers:
10
5
Solution: -15.00
```

Can someone help me understand how rather than subtracting, it's adding the numbers and going negative?

Comment: You're subtracting both numbers. You're not doing a subtraction of one number from another, you're subtracting each number entered from the starting value of 0. Replacing `+` with `-` does work perfectly, if what you're trying to do is subtract all the numbers entered from something.

Comment: What result were you expecting instead?

Comment: Or you already entered `sol` in the code you didn't show. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried.

Comment: I see the problem know and got it fixed. Thanks for the help! @ThomasJager

Comment: do you mean to subtract all subsequently entered numbers from the first one entered, eg `10-5 = 5`? In that case, initialize `sol` to the first number entered, then carry on as you are for the others, it will take a bit more logic.

Answer (score 1):

For subtraction (option 2) you have not assigned `sol` to be the value you wish to subtract from. In your code, you start subtracting from 0 straight away and therefore are left with a negative value.

A fix could be to say that for first number you want to subtract from, set it to be the value of `sol`.

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    scanf("%lf", &subNum);
    if(i == 1)
    {
        sol = subNum;
    }
    else
    {
        sol = sol - subNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it now. I don't know how I didn't realize it was just subtracting from 0 lol. Thx for the reply